# FTP server - directories

Tags: ftp

I have been playing around with several ftp servers and can't get the configuration I want.

I want to allow both anonymous and standard user login, user logins are fine with the default pure-ftpd config (users can get to their home directories), but I'd like anonymous users to have read only access to a subdirectory of my users home directory (~/web/ftp).

Is there anyway to do this with pure-ftpd, or is there an alternative that could?